# How to set up Spektrum wireless buddy-box in Pilot Link mode?

Tags: spektrum

Spektrum's wireless buddy-box trainer is very nice, but how do you set it to use Pilot Link (where only the stick positions are read from the student)?

On the instructor's DX8, we set it to 'Pilot Link Master', but at the student's DX6 we only had options for 'Programmable Master', 'Pilot Link Master' and 'Inhibit'. We tried all three, and while it was using the mixing and trims from the instructor's transmitter, it was still using servo reversing from the student's transmitter.

On older Spektrum radios, there was a 'slave' mode for the student end. Where has that gone?